# 404 on CSS and JS only on Homepage

Tags: 404-error, backup

I had to use a backup of the website and on restoration the Homepage has 404's to all JS/CSS files

Every other page is accessible and does not experience the issue

I've checked the permalinks, I've checked file permissions but the problem persists

```
https://onemoresong.com.au
```

Does the HTAccess need to be altered or this issues with the DB?

Comment: All your css files are missing from your theme, you need to put them back there. Here's an example link of a missing /css/ asset: https://onemoresong.com.au/wp-content/themes/themify-ultrax/themify/css/themify.common.min.css?ver=4.9.9. Your site is loading, which means htaccess is probably good unless it's been customised to load assets. I reckon your theme is missing these /css/ files.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra 'x' in the url on the home page for assets:

```
https://onemoresong.com.au/wp-content/themes/themify-ultrax/themify/css/themify.common.min.css?ver=4.9.9
```

Remove the 'x' from themify-ultrax and your assets load:

```
https://onemoresong.com.au/wp-content/themes/themify-ultra/themify/css/themify.common.min.css?ver=4.9.9
```

Check your home template to make sure you didn't accidentally type x there or in your enqueueing of assets. Lastly check our database for this incorrect naming of the theme (the extra 'x').